# Python: Being asked for input twice and outputting duplicate print statements

Tags: python, list, function, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to finish off my program my adding a menu that allows the user to select a few options that allow the user to store website names and passwords in lists. But there was a problem as soon as I have appended some website names and passwords into their respective vaults where whenn I try to select an option after appending the website names and passwords, "1" for example is the expected input to call the viewapp() function to see the websites and passwords stored so far. The thing is it takes more than twice to call the viewapp() function, where it rejects the first expected input but accepts the 2nd one strangely. Also when I select the 3rd option for the purpose to call summary(), the whole printed summary would print out twice, which is a similar pattern to the menu only accepting the 2nd expected input. The program is doing what I want except for this annoying bug where selecting those four options makes it ask for input a second time when it's supposed to straight away jump to that function. Help would be appreciated.

```
appvault = []
passvault = []

def logged():
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    print("Hello, welcome to the password vault console. ")
    modea = input("""Below are the options you can choose from in the password vault console:
    ##########################################################################\n
    1) Find the password for an existing webiste/app
    2) Add a new website/app and a new password for it
    3) Summary of the password vault
    4) Exit
    ##########################################################################\n
    > """).strip()
    return modea

def viewapp():
    if len(appvault) > 0:
        for app in appvault:
            print("Here is the website/app you have stored:")
            print("- {}\n".format(app))
    if len(passvault) > 0 :
        for code in passvault:
            print("Here is the password you have stored for the website/app: ")
            print("- {}\n".format(code))

    else:
        print("You have no apps or passwords entered yet!")

def addapp(): 
    while True:
        validapp = True
        while validapp:
            new_app = input("Enter the new website/app name: ").strip().lower()
            if len(new_app) > 20:
                print("Please enter a new website/app name no more than 20 characters: ")
            elif len(new_app) < 1:
                print("Please enter a valid new website/app name: ")
            else:
                validapp = False
                appvault.append(new_app)

        validnewpass = True
        while validnewpass:
            new_pass = input("Enter a new password to be stored in the passsword vault: ")
            if not new_pass.isalnum():
                print("Your password for the website/app cannot be null, contain spaces or contain symbols \n")            
            elif len(new_pass) < 8:
                print("Your new password must be at least 8 characters long: ")
            elif len(new_pass) > 20:
                print("Your new password cannot be over 20 characters long: ")   
            else:
                validnewpass = False
                passvault.append(new_pass) 

        validquit = True
        while validquit:
            quit = input("\nEnter 'end' to exit or any key to continue to add more website/app names and passwords for them: \n> ")
            if quit in ["end", "End", "END"]:
                logged()
            else:
                validquit = False
                addapp()
            return addapp        

def summary():
    if len(passvault) > 0:
        for passw in passvault:
            print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print("Here is a summary of the passwords stored in the password vault:\n")
            print("The number of passwords stored:", len(passvault))
            print("Passwords with the longest characters: ", max(new_pass for (new_pass) in passvault))
            print("Passwords with the shortest charactrs: ", min(new_pass for (new_pass) in passvault))
            print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")
    else:
        print("You have no passwords entered yet!")

while True:        
    chosen_option = logged()
    print(chosen_option) 
    if chosen_option == "1":
        viewapp()

    elif chosen_option == "2":
        addapp()   

    elif chosen_option == "3":
        summary()

    elif chosen_option == "4":
        break
    else:
        print("That was not a valid option, please try again: ")

print("Goodbye")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you call `logged()` when exiting `addapp()`:

```
if quit in ["end", "End", "END"]:
    logged()
```

Then, the choice you enter is returned by `logged()`, and thrown away as it isn't assigned to anything.

You're now back at the end of the previous block in `addapp()`, and the next instruction is `return addapp`, that will bring you back to your main loop, where you'll be sent to `logged()` again by `chosen_option = logged()`

Note that in `return addapp`, you return the `addapp` *function* itself, which is certainly not what you want to do. So, as you don't need a return value for `addapp()`, just use `return`,  or nothing at all, Python will automatically return at the end of the function.

So, to solve your problem: directly `return` when you're done entering sites:

```
if quit in ["end", "End", "END"]:
    return
```

Note also that you recursively call `addapp()` from itself when you add more sites.
You should generaly avoid that unless you really want to use some recursive algorithm, and rather use a loop as you did in your main loop. By default, Python limits you to 1000 recursion levels - so you could even crash your app by entering more than 1000 sites in a row ;)

The summary problem is only caused by the unnecessary `for` loop in `summary()`

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there. The issue is in the addapp() function at line 63:

```
if quit not in ["end", "End", "END"]:
    logged()
```

if you replace

```
logged()
```

with

```
pass
```

Then everything will work a ok.
You are not handling the result of the logged function here anyway.
You also do not need to process the logged function here. The addapp will exit and the logged function will be called and handled in the while loop the addapp function was called from.